# Tables with multiple same columns but only join based on few columns in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to filter the `val3` after joining 2 tables. df1 and df2 have 3 same column names ( val1, val2 and val3 )

df_1

```
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|val1|val2|val3|val4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   2|   2|   a|  54|
|  1|   2|   2|   b|  56|
|  2|   3|   4|   c|  12|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

df_2

```
+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|val1|val2|val3|val5|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   2|   2|  aa|  %%|
|  1|   2|   2|  bb|  $#|
|  2|   3|   4|  cc|  @&|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

After doing join 2 tables

`df = df_1.join(df_2, ["val1", "val2"], "left")`

the new table has 2  columns named `val3`

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|val1|val2|val3|val4|val3|val5|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   2|   2|   a|  54|  aa|  %%|
|  1|   2|   2|   b|  56|  bb|  $#|
|  2|   3|   4|   c|  12|  cc|  @&|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

So when I do `where()` filter on `val3`

`df = (df.where(F.col(val3) == "b"))`

but I got there error

`AnalysisException: Reference 'val3' is ambiguous, could be: val3, val3.`

How can I handle this situation? Do I miss something ?

Comment: try renaming `val3` of one of the dataframe using `.withColumnRenamed` before the `JOIN`

Comment: Other way to handle this problem is using `alias`. I prefer the rename solution, as it is simpler.

Comment: when we rename or alias and do filter, how we can know which "val3" or renamed "val3" contains "b" ?

Comment: Can you add expected output? It is not clear if want to filter `df` using values in `df_1`s column, or `df_2`s column, or both.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because after join you get two columns named `val3` and spark cannot figure out which of them you mean.

There are two ways fix it, which one suites you better

1. Give the dataframes aliases, then use `table_alias.column_name` to select the column you need

```py
df_1 = df_1.alias("table_first")
df_2 = df_2.alias("table_second")

df = df_1.join(df_2, ["val1", "val2"], "left")
df = (df.where(F.col("table_first.val3") == "b"))
```

2. Rename columns with repeating names:

```py
df_1 = df_1.withColumnRenamed("val3", "val3_left")
df = df_1.join(df_2, ["val1", "val2"], "left")
df = (df.where(F.col("val3_left") == "b"))
```